# Would one be allowed to suck or squeeze the juice directly out of grapes into his mouth during the 9 days?

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, nine-days

The commonly accepted custom is [not to drink grape juice](https://www.torahmusings.com/2009/08/grape-juice-during-nine-days/) during the nine days, like wine.
Would one be allowed to suck or squeeze the juice directly out of the grapes into his mouth?

Would it make a difference if he also eats the grapes right afterward?

Comment: Why wouod you think grape juice squeezed directly into your mouth versus into a glass would be different?

Comment: @Dude Eating grapes is permitted even though juice comes out. ie squeezing the juice out with teeth is ok. So using your mouth to suck it out is similar. So squeezing it right into the mouth is pretty close too.

Comment: As you say this is just a custom. I don't think there's any custom about sucking drips out of grapes.

Comment: @DoubleAA What about squeezing into mouth? or onto hand and licking it off? Does each and every situation need its own custom??? Its the GJ that we dont drink thats the custom not HOW we drink it.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Based on your response to Double this should be 100% assur. Why do you think this should be different that it needs to be singled out?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore "Does each and every situation need its own custom???" yes.

Comment: Here's something to consider - The bracha on grapes is ha'etz, not hagefen. It makes no difference if you suck the juice out of it while it's in your mouth. You still say ha'etz because it's not considered "wine" or "grape juice". Therefore, I think it's permitted to do this.

Comment: @DanF If one made a meat pie with a mezonos dough one would not say shehakol on the meat, yet it would still be forbidden to eat during the 9 days. The lack of bracha is on the meat is because the meat is a tafel to the dough not because hes not eating meat. Same here the lack of bracha on the GJ when eating it with the grapes is because it is a tafel to the grapes, not because he is not drinking GJ.

Comment: "is not necessarily a good test" - No argument, here. I just think the case of grapes and its juice in this case, might come under the ikar / tafel criteria or simply that sucking juice out of the fruit may be considered as if your eating the whole fruit. For now, I'm going with the 2nd idea. I have to research what the general rule is about doing this, such as sucking oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether sucking juice out of a fruit is considered as if you are eating the fruit itself, or whether you are extracting its juice. There is a machloket on this as explained, [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=1724):

> We must now discuss a situation where one only sucks out the juice of
>   a fruit without actually biting into or eating the fruit itself: Is
>   this similar to one who drinks fruit juice and recites a “Shehakol”
>   blessing or should it be considered like one is eating the fruit and
>   he will subsequently recite a “Boreh Peri Ha’etz” blessing? Indeed, we
>   find that the Poskim disagree about this matter. The Peri Chadash
>   proves from the Rambam that sucking is halachically tantamount to
>   eating, for the Rambam quotes the Geonim as saying that one who sucks
>   on a sugar cane recites the “Boreh Peri Ha’adama” blessing. Clearly,
>   sucking is equivalent to eating and not to drinking. Hagaon Harav
>   Yehuda Ayash and others rule accordingly.
>
> On the other hand, Hagaon Rabbeinu Akiva Eiger and Hagaon Harav Yosef
>   Yedid Ha’Levi prove from the words of the Tosafot that sucking is
>   comparable to drinking for which one recites the “Shehakol” blessing.

Thus, according to the opinion that sucking is like eating, you would be allowed to suck out the GJ during the Nine Days, but not according to the 2nd opinion.

Comment: Would sucking grapes get a hagafen or a shehakol? I don't see that you've addressed that. It could be drinking juice from a grape but not drinking grape juice. According to the drinking side, can I say Kiddush on whole grapes and suck out the juice after??