# Sucking a citrus fruit: Kaf Hachayim

Tags: halacha, blessing, eating, fruits, acharonim

[The *Kaf Hachayim*, *OC* 202:63](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.202.63):

> ומיהו המוצץ משקה מן הפרי חשוב אוכל ומברך ברכתו הראויה לו ושיעורו בכזית לברך ברכה אחרונה. פר״ח בספרו מים חיים סימן ז׳ חס״ל אות י״ד. והיינו דוקא במוצצם ע״י לעיסה שנותנם בפיו דכיון שצריך היא ללעוס בשיניו דיינינן ליה כאוכל ושיעורו בכזית אבל מציצה שאין בה לעיסה שתופס הפרי בידו ומוצצו הרי זה דינו כשתייה

He says that sucking juice from a fruit is considered eating (and requires a fruit-specific benediction beforehand) if "he sucks them through *laos*-ing, that he puts them in his mouth;… he needs to *laos* with his teeth". On the other hand, "sucking that does not have *laos*-ing, that he holds the fruit in his hand and sucks it, is considered drinking" (and requires juice's benediction).

(I don't know whether by "*laos*" he means to bite or to chew or something in between or something else, which is why I didn't translate it.)

What if someone holds a quarter or eighth of a citrus fruit in his hand, puts part of it in his mouth, bites down with his front teeth, and sucks? This is, I think, the most common way of sucking juice from a citrus fruit. Would the *Kaf Hachayim* consider that eating (perhaps because he bit down) or drinking (perhaps because he didn't put the fruit into his mouth and chew)?

Comment: relevant: [Would one be allowed to suck or squeeze the juice directly out of grapes into his mouth during the 9 days?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93817/11501)